Lucoms bios and ecs h81h3-m3 motherboard = no support
I have a ECS H81H3-M3 motherboard(LGA 1150) which has drivers here but only for windows and Lucoms bios and MSI GTX 460
Ubuntu can run on this but with random freeze to death and sometimes not able to wake up from suspend.
Is it possible that folks at Ubuntu can make drivers for this?
Also any list of motherboards that are officially tested and supported by Ubuntu?
